# Appropiate name for coefficients of meta-regression

Tags: meta-regression

I would like to report the slope coefficient of several meta-regressions with one predictor. I am wondering what the correct term for this coefficient is. Is it simply b1 or is it β?

Comment: There is no correct term, the notation is a matter of preference. For the purpose of publishing in a scholarly journal, I generally recommend that no notation is used at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What would you recommend instead to put as a column heading in a table?

Comment: You can say "Coefficient", "Slope" or "Mean difference". And in the footnote, clarify precisely where it comes from in the model..